# TCP/IP Client -> Recibir

Tags: c#

Estoy conectando un indicador de peso, he construido un programa que envía y recibe datos por puertos y conexión ip me he logrado conectar al indicador pero no recibo ningún dato al yo mandarle un comando  solo me responde FAIL
Lo que necesito es que me mande el peso que la bascula da 
Capturar el 4.7

**INDICADOR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PROGRAMA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Manual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO**

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cliente
{
    public partial class Cliente : Form
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpClient Client;

        private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            Client.Connect(txtHost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            Client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            Client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                //e.ReplyLine(string.Format("you said:{0}", e.MessageString));

            });
        }

        private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client.WriteLineAndGetReply(txtMessage.Text,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes la documentación de dicho dispositivo?

Comment: Si, mira la imagen que subí solo tengo eso

Comment: ¿De dónde sacaste la idea de mandar un GET? Tienes otras 2 preguntas que son muy similares...

Comment: te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Esta es la cuarta pregunta sobre el mismo tema. Ha cambiado el problema en cada una?

Comment: Son diferentes, si el problema es diferente en cada una

Comment: Estaba mandando comandos para mirar si me daba respuesta